# Error when passing intent from one activity to another activity in Kotlin, android studio

Tags: java, android

The IDE shows an error in .java. please tell me what is wrong here.
[image]

```
Handler().postDelayed({
        Toast.makeText(applicationContext,"This is Splash Screen",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        val intent = Intent(this, ScreenTwo::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
        finish()
    }, SPLASH_TIMER.toLong())

}
```

Comment: have you tried to run the project see if error go away

Comment: I executed the code it executes successfully and shows the desired output but that error and red line are still there, and in the problems tab, it shows "unresolved reference: java"

Comment: It can be Ide aka Android Studio's bug so relax nothing to worry about ;)

Answer (score -1):

```
package com.example.intent;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button btn;
        btn =findViewById(R.id.btnnext);
        Intent inext;
        inext=new Intent(MainActivity.this,Secondactivity.class);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(inext);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Calculate:

```
package com.example.calculatorbmi;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText edtweight, edtHeightFt, edtHeightIn;
    Button btnCalculate;
    TextView txtResult;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        edtweight = findViewById(R.id.edtWeight);

        edtHeightFt = findViewById(R.id.edtheight);

        edtHeightIn = findViewById(R.id.edithei);

        btnCalculate = findViewById(R.id.btncal);

        txtResult = findViewById(R.id.txtresult);
        btnCalculate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override

            public void onClick(View v) {

                int wt = Integer.parseInt(edtweight.getText().toString());

                int ft = Integer.parseInt(edtHeightFt.getText().toString());

                int in = Integer.parseInt(edtHeightIn.getText().toString());

                int totalIn = ft * 12 + in;

                double totalCm = totalIn * 2.53;

                double totalM = totalCm / 100;

                double bmi = wt / (totalM * totalM);

                if (bmi > 25) {

                    txtResult.setText("You're Overweight!");

                } else if (bmi < 18) {

                    txtResult.setText("You're UnderWeight");

                } else {

                    txtResult.setText("You're Healthy");

                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Validation:

```
private boolean isValidEmail(String email){
    return Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher (email).matches();
}

private boolean isValid Mobile(string mobile) {
    return mobile.length() == 10 && android.text.TextUtils.isDigitsOnly(mobile);
}
```